# How to blur edges of lines using CGContext

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am drawing lines using CGContext but I want to make its edges blur. I have checked shadows, but in shadows the edges of lines are not soft & smooth. Kindly tell me what can I do to make the edges of lines blur.

Here's the [code link](https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by blurring the "edges" of lines, but you could try drawing the same path with a larger line width first, and then draw the path with progressively thinner and darker lines.

Comment: Please tell me how can i do this in some details?

Comment: Once you've made some sort of path in your context, to draw the path you call CGContextStrokePath. Before doing so, you can set the line width and color with which to draw, using CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor and CGContextSetLineWidth. As an easy example, you can draw the line 3 times, first with a line width of 10 pixels and a color of some sort of pale grey, then with a width of 5 pixels and a darker grey, and then with a width of 2 pixels and a pure black.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The point of this approach is a sort of makeshift way to do a gradient centered around the line that you draw. The progressive layers of thicker and more faded lines are in fact the "gradient," saving you from having to outline the entire path and draw  a real gradient using CGGradients.

Answer (score -1):

Other Way Of the Draw the Line..I hope this is USeful to draw the line and Increse the line Width...

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        //// DRAW LINE....


           UIView *lineView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, 3)] autorelease];

           //Replece the 3 and put the 5 for Increse the line Width

            lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            lineView.autoresizingMask = 0x5f;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
            }
```

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question. This code is adding a narrow subview to give the appearance of a straight line, the question is about drawing paths.

Comment: Agreed its all about CGContext although the subview approach would work as a replacement for an image I guess